# Sequelize not defined

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize for my orm database. I'm using mysql.

I got this error when run the project.

```
var accounts = sequelize.define('OkAkun' , {//attrbut 
                         ^

ReferenceError: sequelize is not defined
    at module.exports (/path_to_project/Backend/app/models/OkAkun.js:7:26)
    at Sequelize.import (/path_to_project/Backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:691:30)
    at /path_to_project/Backend/app/models/index.js:30:32
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path_to_project/Backend/app/models/index.js:29:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path_to_project/Backend/app/routes/routers.js:4:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
```

Take a look for my file

> index.js

```
"use strict";
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require ('path');
var Sequelize = require ('sequelize');
var basename = path.basename(module.filename);
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
var dbConfig =require(__base + "config/initializers/config.js").database;
var sequelize;

sequelize = new  Sequelize(dbConfig[env].database , dbConfig[env].username , dbConfig[env].password,
            {
                "dialect": "mysql",
                "host"  :dbConfig[env].host,
                "port"  :dbConfig[env].port,
                "logging": false,
                "define": {underscored: true}
            });

var db = {};

fs
.readdirSync(__dirname)
.filter(function(file){
    return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== basename);
})
 .forEach(function(file) {
    var model  = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname,file));
    db[model.name] = model;
 });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function (modelName){
    if("associate" in db[modelName]){
        db[modelName].associate(db);
    }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;



module.exports = db;
```

and this is my model. When i run the project. it show error that sequelize not defined.

> OkAkun.js

```
module.exports  = function () {

var accounts = sequelize.define('OkAkun' , {//attrbut 

    id_akun : {
        autoIncrement: true,
        type : DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey : true
    },
    username:{
        type : DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    phone_number:{
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull:false
    },
    email : {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    create_at : {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false    
    },
    update_at : {
        type : DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false
    },
    password : {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
});

return accounts;

};
```

Fyi, i'm new in using orm for the database like sequelize. And i don't understand what step i missing here.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `sequelize` and `DataTypes` to your model function's arguments. Sequelize will pass these in when you do `sequelize.import`.

See also https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/blob/master/models/task.js for a working example

Comment: Yes that's it. Thank You. But it got other error. Table  'OkAkuns' does not exist.  My table is 'OkAkun' without 's'  as i defined in the Model OkAkun.js. 

What i miss here ? thx

Comment: can you add any link tutorial to use sequelize from zero please.

Comment: Sequelize will automatically pluralise your model name when determining the table name. You can disable this by passing `freezeTableName: true ` to the model options. The official documentation is a good place to start; it's where I learned Sequelize :) https://sequelize.readthedocs.org